# How to get reputation points so I can comment, vote, answer?

Tags: discussion, community

So I love this site. Usually I find an answer right away. But sometimes I do find another solution or simply want to comment on instructions and what I had to do perhaps differently because of my hardware. I would like to upvote  certain really GREAT answers.

So my question is basically if I can't answer, comment, or vote... how can I obtain reputation points and contribute? Of course I understand the reasoning (needing experienced commenters) but what I'm facing is all my qestions get answered here, so I can barely contribute to solutions. High-class problems I know since I'm getting 95% of my learning done via this site.

Comment: One way is to edit some of the posts - fixing spelling error et al.  When accepted, you do gain points.  Also answering questions, if you know the answer, or asking good questions.

Comment: _Charles Green_ is absolutely correct, and that's how I got started.

Comment: I don't get to ask many questions because I tend to find ALL my answers here, ;)